# AWS Aurora and Auto-increment

Tags: amazon-aurora

We consider switching our existing MySql-cluster database into AWS Aurora. 
Does Aurora support Auto-increment column?
Suppose the answer is YES - 
Does Aurora's Multi-Master support Auto-increment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aurora is "MySQL compatible".  From the FAQ:

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/

"most of the code, applications, drivers and tools you already use today with your MySQL databases can be used with Aurora with little or no change."

That should include autoincrement columns unless otherwise specified, and that is not mentioned in list of MySQL features not supported in Aurora:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.AuroraMySQL.Overview.html#Aurora.AuroraMySQL.CompareReleases